# Shape issues in Training a Keras Model

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, reshape, tf.keras

Here is the code that I have written:

```
Df_input = df_close[input_col]
df_Output = df_close[Output_cols]
def preprocess_multistep_lstm(Input_Sequence, Output_Sequence, n_steps_in, n_steps_out, features, ):
    X, y = list(), list()
    for i in range(len(Input_Sequence)):
        # find the end of this pattern
        end_ix = i + n_steps_in
        out_end_ix = end_ix + n_steps_out
        # check if we are beyond the sequence
        if out_end_ix > len(Input_Sequence):
            break
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        seq_x, seq_y = Input_Sequence[i:end_ix], Output_Sequence[end_ix:out_end_ix]
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)
#         if i == 0:
#             print(seq_x)
#             print(seq_y)

    X = np.array(X)
    y = np.array(y)

    X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], X.shape[1], -n_features))
    print(X)
    return X, y
# choose the number of days on which to base our predictions 

output_needed = 1
Seq_len = 2

n_features = 1

# X, y = preprocess_lstm(df_close_shift.to_numpy(), nb_days, n_features)
X, y = preprocess_multistep_lstm(Df_input.to_numpy(), df_Output.to_numpy(), Seq_len, output_needed, n_features)
```

The above is the way I am generating data for the training.

#Split the data set b

```
etween the training set and the test set
test_days = 365 

X_train, y_train = X[:-test_days], y[:-test_days]
X_test, y_test = X[-test_days:], y[-test_days:]  
model = Sequential()
Test_model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=50, input_shape=(Seq_len, n_features)))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])  
epoch = 1
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(model=model)
manager = tf.train.CheckpointManager(
        checkpoint, 
        directory="EURUSD/model", 
        max_to_keep=2,
        checkpoint_name="model_1_2_3_4"
    )
while epoch < 10:
    model.fit(X_train, 
              y_train, 
              epochs=1, 
              batch_size = 32)
    
    # Evaluate the model on the test data using
    print("Evaluate on test data")
    results = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=32)
    print("Test MSE:", results[0])
    print("Test MAE:", results[1])
    manager.save()
    epoch = epoch + 1
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1377, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1360, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1349, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1126, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\input_spec.py", line 298, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential_8' (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "lstm_3" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, None, 1), found shape=(None, 2, 74)
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'sequential_8' (type Sequential):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 2, 74), dtype=float32)
      • training=True
      • mask=None
```

I know I am missing something and not able to understand what exactly I have missed.
please can someone let me know how I can resolve this issue?

If I change the line `X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], X.shape[1], -n_features))` to `X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], X.shape[1], n_features))` then I am getting the following error:

`ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 147704 into shape (998,2,1)`